# Advantages of full Wave Rectifier Compared to Half Wave Rectifier

Tags: homework

I have a homework assignment. Our teacher wanted us to research advantages of full wave rectifier compared to half wave rectifier or just advantages of full wave rectifier. I researched it and found something is like below.

Full wave uses two area, positive and negative ones. But half wave uses just one area, negative or positive one.

Full wave has much less ripple voltage than half wave.

RMS voltage of full wave is higher than half wave.

But I want to know more advantages which is not known so much. Are there any advantages like I said ?

Comment: then research some more.

Comment: You could compare the frequency (Fourier) spectrum for each and speculate why one may be preferable to the other.

Comment: Of your 3 points, the first is a textbook definition. The other 2 points are real-world results that are usually favorable. Examine the advantages of these 2 points in all their applications, such as high-power output, low power draw, high frequency, radio frequencies, etc.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I have been already searching but there are same results at every source of internet and I wanted to ask here.

Comment: There is information beyond the Internet. Information can even be created; for example, by making things and doing experiments. But start with organising your thoughts : what constitutes an advantage? Given two circuits, if you are told to decide the better one, your first problem is to understand what "better" means.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thank you so much to expand my point of view. As you said, I should prepare some circuits and compare them. If I can't find extra information, I should compose them.

Comment: Full wave rectifiers bring a disadvantage; peak volt drop is twice that of a half wave rectifier.

Comment: @Andyaka What do you want to say excatly ? Why this is disadvantage ? Maybe dropping will be twice but I guess it is worth than be zero for a half period.

Comment: It’s a bid disadvantage in several type of rectifier circuits. Bridge rectification is also a massive disadvantage in flyback transformers too. You were focusing on advantages so I pointed this out in case you might have been interested.

Comment: Please don't misunderstand me, all answer is significant for me. You mentioned interesting point and I was suprised. Thank you so much your explaining. @Andyaka